# Clock Synchronization using ptp4l

Tags: time, clock, ptp

I am trying to synchronize clocks using `ptp4l` and `phc2sys`.

I followed this [instructions](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/sec-using_ptp#sec-Starting_ptp4l).
Unfortunately, I am seeing clock jumps:
In 5 of the 6 servers, clock jumps by 2 hours. In the image, it goes from 9:52 to 11:46.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was arising because of different timestamps on the CPU clock and the NIC.
NIC was two hours ahead and caused the time to change for all other systems.

These two commands worked for me:

```
sudo ptp4l -i <interface> -2 
sudo phc2sys -a -rr
```

-2        IEEE 802.3

-i        interface

-a        turn on autoconfiguration

-rr       synchronize system (realtime) clock and also consider it as a time source